# Creating bigrams of words not letters

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am trying to create bigrams from some text in a given column in my dataframe. The problem is my code splits the sentences in my dataframe to letters and not bigrams (as in two words)

This is a sample of my dataframe

```
    favorites   location    retweets    tweet_text
2832    0   Washington, DC  238517  RT @SpaceX: Liftoff! http
2864    802842  Washington, DC  213853  The United States of America will be designating ANTIFA as a Terrorist Organization.
2851    0   Washington, DC  213853  RT @realDonaldTrump: The United States of America will be designating ANTIFA as a Terrorist Organization.
2914    778873  Washington, DC  146570  CHINA!
288 606090  Washington, DC  138520  IF YOU CAN PROTEST IN PERSON, YOU CAN VOTE IN PERSON!
```

My code:

```
import nltk
df['bigrams'] = df['tweet_text'].apply(lambda row: list(nltk.ngrams(row, 2)))
```

and my output:

```
    favorites   location    retweets    tweet_text  bigrams
0   42557   Washington, DC  6500    Landing in New Hampshire!   [(L, a), (a, n), (n, d), (d, i), (i, n), (n, g), (g, ), ( , i), (i, n), (n, ), ( , N), (N, e), (e, w), (w, ), ( , H), (H, a), (a, m), (m, p), (p, s), (s, h), (h, i), (i, r), (r, e), (e, !)]
1   68523   Washington, DC  16901   No, I want Big Ten, and all other football, back - NOW. The Dems don’t want football back, for political reasons, but are trying to blame me and the Republicans. Another LIE, but this is what we are up against! They should also open up all of their Shutdown States.   [(N, o), (o, ,), (,, ), ( , I), (I, ), ( , w), (w, a), (a, n), (n, t), (t, ), ( , B), (B, i), (i, g), (g, ), ( , T), (T, e), (e, n), (n, ,), (,, ), ( , a), (a, n), (n, d), (d, ), ( , a), (a, l), (l, l), (l, ), ( , o), (o, t), (t, h), (h, e), (e, r), (r, ), ( , f), (f, o), (o, o), (o, t), (t, b), (b, a), (a, l), (l, l), (l, ,), (,, ), ( , b), (b, a), (a, c), (c, k), (k, ), ( , -), (-, ), ( , N), (N, O), (O, W), (W, .), (., ), ( , T), (T, h), (h, e), (e, ), ( , D), (D, e), (e, m), (m, s), (s, ), ( , d), (d, o), (o, n), (n, ’), (’, t), (t, ), ( , w), (w, a), (a, n), (n, t), (t, ), ( , f), (f, o), (o, o), (o, t), (t, b), (b, a), (a, l), (l, l), (l, ), ( , b), (b, a), (a, c), (c, k), (k, ,), (,, ), ( , f), (f, o), (o, r), (r, ), ( , p), (p, o), (o, l), (l, i), (i, t), (t, i), ...]
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to pass `nltk.ngrams` a list of words if you want it to produce ngrams like that.

So the simplest solution is to modify your code to pass a list of words like this:

```
df['bigrams'] = df['tweet_text'].apply(lambda row: list(nltk.ngrams(row.split(), 2)))
```

That'll split words on whitespace, so that for

```
IF YOU CAN PROTEST IN PERSON, YOU CAN VOTE IN PERSON!
```

One of the bigrams you get is `('IN', 'PERSON,')` (note the comma).

If you want to split the word slightly differently (depends on your application), you'll probably want to make your own method to split the `row` into words, and call that on `row` instead of calling `row.split()`.

Comment: Why not prefer the more idiomatic `nltk.word_tokenize` instead of `str.split`?

Comment: Because I don't know `nltk`. `word_tokenize(row)` is probably a better choice than `row.split()`